# JBOSS 7.1 server is not starting in linux mint 17.3

Tags: jboss7.x, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 17.3  .  i want to configure JBOSS server in my system. whenever i command **sh.standalone.sh** it is showing following screen but doesnot starting server.

```
  indra@Jarvis ~/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin $ sh standalone.sh 
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /home/indra/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
09:45:02,152 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
09:45:02,517 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
09:45:02,629 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
^C09:47:05,537 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" stopped in 1ms
```

i wait for 15 min but it is not starting .
please someone guide me.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final does not work with Java 8, https://developer.jboss.org/message/926279#926279. You consider migrating to [WildFly 10](http://wildfly.org) as it requires Java 8.